# How to use Flickr api to make Image Gallery using React native

Tags: react-native, api, flickr

I already made working a gallery app  with dummy data and now i want to use flickr image data
but idk how to use this flickr api and fetch the data using it.

i want to fetch flickr "recent photos" from explore tab of flicker website
to use in my gallery

This is the import statement of data file which i'm currently using for dummy data

```
let data = require('../Data.json')
```

And this is implementation of it through FlatList

```
  <FlatList
        horizontal={false}
        numColumns={3}
        data={data}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
           
        <TouchableOpacity
          
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("GalleryPhoto",item)}
          >
                 <View style={{flex:1}}>
        
          <Image
                source={{ uri: item.photo }}
                style={{ width: 140, height: 140 }}
          />
    
            </View>
          
          
          </TouchableOpacity>
```

this is the github repo for the code
https://github.com/adiruv/GalleryAppReactNative

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Sign Up for Flicker.

- Go to Flicker website and sign up.
- SignUp Page: https://identity.flickr.com/sign-up

### 2. Then apply for the API key.

- https://www.flickr.com/services/apps/create/apply/
- [image]

### 3. Create a request URL with parameter including your API key.

- Create URL to search images.

```js
const yourApiKey = 'your api comes here';

const data = {
  method: 'flickr.photos.search',
  api_key: yourApiKey,
  text: 'cat', // Search Text
  sort: 'interestingness-desc',
  per_page: 12,
  license: '4',
  extras: 'owner_name,license',
  format: 'json',
  nojsoncallback: 1,
};

const parameters = new URLSearchParams(data);

const url = `https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?${parameters}`;
console.log(url);
```

### 4. Make a request with that URL.

```js
const url = `https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?${parameters}`;

axios.get(url)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    // We will impliment something later...
  });
```

### 5. Create ImageURL from the API response.

- With the request above, you can only get meta datas of the photos.
- So you need to create ImageURL（image source url） to actually display the image.
- Also check the Size Suffixes to configure the size of the images: https://www.flickr.com/services/api/misc.urls.html

```js
const getFlickrImageURL = (photo, size) => {
  let url = `https://farm${photo.farm}.staticflickr.com/${photo.server}/${photo.id}_${
    photo.secret
  }`;
  if (size) {
    // Configure image size
    url += `_${size}`;
  }
  url += '.jpg';
  return url;
};

const url = `https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?${parameters}`;

axios.get(url)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => (
    // get an array of image-url
    data.photos.photo.map((photo) => {
      return getFlickrImageURL(photo, 'q');
    })
  ));
```

### 6. Display Images

- Now you've got an array of the imageURLs from flicker API.
- You can loop over the array and display it as you wish.

Comment: what is the array name here and where exactly it get exported for the use ... I'm using FlatList to display data with the array name "data"... sorry i'm kinda new to this , also ill add the github link of the code in question